# Docker image - persisting data after image deletion

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I recently started playing around with docker because I thought it'd be good to have my site dockerised. I have a super simple docker-compose.yml file which contains wordpress:latest and mysql:5.7 only.

I copied this file to my server and ran it using `docker-compose up -d` and it ws running fine.  I hit the front-end, which presented me with the WordPress admin set up page. Great! I set it up and I made a post, navigated to my domain and I could see the post fine - all is good.

...However!

I then became intrigued with data persistence and wanted to know what would happen if my images stopped running and if i started them up again with the same command. I stopped the containers, started them again and my new post was still there. Perfect. I then wanted to delete my images and start afresh so I stopped my running images and then deleted the images themselves using `docker rmi blah/blah:blah`. I ran `docker images ls` and all the images were gone, as expected. I then re-ran my docker-compose file. The images were gone so it downloaded the target images again and I navigated to my domain in a browser expecting to see the wordpress setup page again... but my previous data was still there, even my post was still there in wordpress. I don't understand how deleting the images and re-downloading them hasn't wiped all of the data. Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I don't really know what.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: need a bit more info about this. Did you have a volume `-v` flag which pointed to your local machine folder? If so, since the image uses the same folder each time, that could be the reason for this persistence. Just remove the data from this folder also.

Comment: This could be it! I have `image: mysql:5.7 volumes: - db_data:/var/lib/mysql` inside my docker-compose file! I presume then, that the database table is mounted on my server and not inside the image? I also have `volumes:  db_data: {}` at the tail end of the file

Comment: instead of using db_data you can put a local folder `/somelocalfolder:/var/lib/mysql` then you can delete these contents. But the named volume you use is more elegant. To delete a volume use `docker volume ls and docker volume rm <id>`

Answer (score 1):

As per comments above, data is persisted via the volume (or -v argument) to a directory on the server accessible by containers. My volume is set to `/var/lib/mysql` in docker-compose, however, the true directory seems to be `/var/lib/docker/volumes/root_db_data/_data/mysql`